# Fill any of the 2 cells, automatically fill the other

Tags: excel, google-sheets

I have a simple spreadsheet with net and gross prices. Sometimes it's easier for me to fill in one, sometimes the other. I'd like to make sure that once I fill in net price, then automatically gross price will be updated (net * 1.23) and vice versa (gross / 1.23). How can I achieve this? When I simply write `=b1/1.23` and `a1*1.23` then I get circular dependency error and it doesn't look nicely. I'd like to have those columns empty until someone fills in one of the cell and then the other should automatically update.

P.S. I'm tagging both google sheets (which I'm using) and Microsoft Excel, as I'm assuming that the solution might be the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to enable the circular dependency (you can do from the options both in Microsoft Excel and Libreoffice Calc don't know about google sheets), at that point when you put a value in one cell, the other is automatically updated.

#### Google Sheets

To resolve circular references in Google Sheets enable the "Iterative calculation" option. To do so go on `File>Spreadsheet Settings>Calculation>Toggle the Iterative calculation switch`